# Creating a buffer for each row in a shapefile

Tags: arcpy, buffer, cursor

My input is a point shapefile with more than 500 features. I need to create separate shapefiles with a buffer of 15 kilometers around each feature (so the output will be more than 500 shapefiles with only one feature/row in each). I am using `arcpy.SearchCursor()`, so the code is run for each row. Here is my code but I keep getting the error that "Cannot create output 3001_Buffer.shp".

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial") 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

output_workspace = "C:/Prog_Data/Output"
arcpy.env.workspace = output_workspace

fc = "C:/Prog_Data/data_570_pr.shp"
field = "codi"
shapefieldname = "Shape"

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    feat = row.getValue(shapefieldname) 
    val = row.getValue(field)
    val_st = str(val)
    val_adj = val_st.replace('.0', '')
    outFC = str(val_adj) + "_Buffer" + ".shp" 
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(feat, outFC, "15 Kilometers", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR") 

print("done")
```

Comment: #1 rule of ArcGIS cursors: Do not use `arcpy.SearchCursor`. Only use Data Access cursors (`arcpy.da.SearchCursor`).  It's also a violation of database naming principles to use a leading numeric character in a dataset name. In 35 years of GIS application development, it's always been enough to have one dataset and  a selection set or definition query -- do you *really* need 3000+ more files in your filesystem?

Comment: Use os path join to combine paths, so replace `outFC = str(val_adj) + "_Buffer" + ".shp"` with  `outFC = os.path.join(str(val_adj),"_Buffer" + ".shp")`. You can buffer everything once then split by attributes.

Comment: Thanks @Vince and BERA, this worked pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

Consider [buffering](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm) all the points in your initial file with the dissolve attribute set to None, and then splitting the features into individual files using [Split by Attributes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/split-by-attributes.htm) with a unique ID as the split field.

```python
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial") 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

output_workspace = "C:/Prog_Data/Output"
arcpy.env.workspace = output_workspace

fc = "C:/Prog_Data/data_570_pr.shp"
field = "codi"
shapefieldname = "Shape"

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(feat, "Buffer_all.shp", "15 Kilometers", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR") 

arcpy.SplitByAttributes_analysis('Buffer_all.shp', output_workspace, ['ID'])

print("done")
```

If you truly need shapefiles instead of separate layers in a feature dataset you could write further code to iterate through each layer in the feature dataset and export to shapefile using [Feature Class to Shapefile](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-shapefile.htm).

Comment: This was also an interesting option but I didn't want to create all buffers simultaneously because some of them would overlap (making it difficult to compute zonal statistics afterwards).

Comment: In this approach you still split the buffers into their own layers, so in terms of zonal stats it doesn't matter if you did the buffering all at once. You could also make a single buffered non-dissolved layer, and then use a search cursor to select each buffer, using that selection as your zonal stats input. That would be a much cleaner file structure than storing the buffers in individual shapefiles.

Comment: I see, thanks @ycartwhelen, I misunderstood your approach. This is indeed more efficient.